# How to run Python code in RStudio from Anaconda without using R reticulate package (directly with Python interpreter without any R involvement

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rstudio

I want to use RStudio from Anaconda for Python development. But I do not want to use any code conversions and etc., like using R reticulate package which is used by RStudio as default. I need that in order to run Python code directly with Python interpreter in order to get maximum Python performance. How can I do it?

*Why RStudio? Because I find it much better than other IDEs for Python that I have tested.*

Comment: You can use Python as an engine in RMarkdown documents https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html Beyond that, you might need to make a clear example so folks can see what you're trying to do exactly

Comment: Do you want to run python in interactive mode or in stdin? Do you want to run it with R script? Is your entire file .py?

Comment: @Jacky I want to run from RStudio `.py` but directly by anaconda Python, without R reticulate package.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option right now is to use [RMarkdown](https://rstudio.com/solutions/r-and-python/). This gives you that Jupyter style code execution but I'm sure you probably already knew that.

There's currently no way to run python natively in RStudio's interactive mode without running `reticulate` but, consider the following:

- You can download [atom](https://atom.io/) and use the [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) add-on. I personally use this when developing on python.
- Use Jupyter Notebook, Spyder or Pycharm (which are decent IDE's but not the purpose of your question.)
- Don't use an IDE. I think [Tech with Tim](https://youtu.be/XHPTq56U06Q) explains why you shouldn't quite well.

Comment: RMarkdown still uses reticulate for python executions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the r system function to call python to run your script:

```
system('python script.py')
```

Just make sure python is on the path.